# Is it possible to reanimate a dragon on skyrim?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Dragons are EXTREMELY powerful and I was wondering if I could get one to fight for me.

Answer (score 8):

It does not appear possible to re-animate dragons.  Although the [Skyrim Wiki](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Reanimate) does point out that attempting to reanimate a dragon corpse may cause it to appear to "fly" temporarily.

> Using a reanimate spell on Dragon corpses causes them to be pushed or thrown/flung wildly into the air.

Answer (score 5):

By default **you can't** even reanimate *giants* not to mention the flying dragons.

There is also a bug that can cause dragons to be pushed or thrown/flung wildly into the air by casting reanimate..

Answer (score 4):

In the dawnguard dlc you recieve a shout called summon Durnehvir. He is technically dead considering you summon him from the Soul Cairn which is sort of like a Lymbo world. I looked for a way to revive various dragons too. Other than that, its just the primary call dragon shout you get from the main story.

Answer (score 3):

Further on in the main quest line, you'll get a shout which calls a dragon to fight for you. Just keep on playing.

Answer (score 1):

There's no possible way to revive dragons. As @Ebongo mentioned:

> It does not appear possible to re-animate dragons. Although the Skyrim Wiki does point out that attempting to reanimate a dragon corpse may cause it to appear to "fly" temporarily, as seen in the below video.

I see that the reason why you need to revive a dragon is so you can have a dragon ally. Here are the ways of doing that:

- During the Main Quest Line, you'll get a shout called "Summon Ohdaving". You must at least complete the main questline for another use. This will summon the dragon who will help you in your battles.
- If you have the Dawnguard DLC, you can receive a shout called "Summon Durnegvir". Just like the Ohdaving shout, you can use it to summon a dragon to help you in your battles.

There's a shout called Resurrection shout, used by Alduin in "A Blade on the Dark". However, it can't be retrieved in vanilla Skyrim, since there are no dungeons or dragon sites with word walls that have this shout. You need to use cheats for mods to get this special shout.

Answer (score -2):

As listed above, there's the Call Dragon shout and the Summon Durnehviir shout that you can use to bring one of two named dragons to fight for you .

There's also the Bend Will shout from the Dragonborn DLC that you can get, which allows you to "bend the will" of a dragon (and other NPCs who are not dead) to fight for you. An additional bonus of this shout is that it allows you actually ride dragons into battle.